# ActionTypes.OpenUrl in ThumbnailCard with "tel:" URI doesn't open call in Teams Desktop Client

Tags: .net, botframework, microsoft-teams

Our Microsoft Teams bot answers searches for contacts return a `ThumbnailCard` containing the name, picture and an `ActionButton` (Type `OpenUrl`) for the users to be able to voice call this contact.

Phone number format used is `tel:+4314023596` which should be proper for this URI schema.

There's an inconsistency in which situations that works

Working:

- Using the Teams iPhone app, the phone opens the "call this number now?" dialog
- Using the emulator on the desktop, Skype for Business is properly opened with the correct number passed to the application

Not Working:

- The Teams Desktop client ignores the very same `ActionButton` by doing "nothing" when clicking on it.
- The Teams Web Client opens a blank page, in the console it returns the error `Invalid URL received: tel:+4314023596`

Goal is that on every device and client the default way on how to place a voice call should be placed. Any hints please what I'm doing wrong?

Here's how I build the `ActionButton`, `cleannumber` is a valid phone number without spaces and parenthesis, starting with `+<countrycode>`.

```cs
CardAction ca = new CardAction()
{
    Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
    Title = "Call",
    Value = "tel:" + cleannumber
};
```

Comment: Is `43676xyz` specifically what you're getting back? In other words, it is translating `4314023596 ` into `43676xyz`?

Comment: No sorry for the confusion, the "Invalid URL received: tel:+43676xyz" error returns the very same number used, no magic there just I don't know why it doesn't work on the Teams Client

Comment: "xyz" was just a placeholder in this example for the correct number displayed in the error message, the number is correctly shown in the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not supported for Desktop client and browser right now. This is part of our backlog.